# retrieving information from related tables with Zend Framework and Doctrine 1.2

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

After working hard in my ZF/Doctrine integration I'm having a problem "translating" my previous Zend_Db work into Doctrine. I used generate-models-db to create the models and I did got to access some properties form the view but only those concerning the table whose model I created like this:

```
$usuarios = new Model_Users();
$usr = $usuarios->getTable()->findAll();
$this->view->show = $usr;
```

Model_Users is related to two tables with this method:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->hasMany('Model_PlanillaUsers as PlanillaUsers', array(
         'local' => 'id',
         'foreign' => 'users_id'));

    $this->hasMany('Model_UsersHasPais as UsersHasPais', array(
         'local' => 'id',
         'foreign' => 'users_id'));
}
```

Right now I'm concerned about UsersHasPais...which tells me what pais.pais fields and which users.id entries match. This is the Model_Pais:

```
abstract class Model_Base_Pais extends Doctrine_Record
{
public function setTableDefinition()
{
    $this->setTableName('pais');
    $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => true,
         'autoincrement' => true,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('pais', 'string', 20, array(
         'type' => 'string',
         'length' => 20,
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
}

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->hasMany('Model_UsersHasPais as UsersHasPais', array(
         'local' => 'id',
         'foreign' => 'pais_id'));
}
}
```

And this is the join table:

```
abstract class Model_Base_UsersHasPais extends Doctrine_Record
{
public function setTableDefinition()
{
    $this->setTableName('users_has_pais');
    $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => true,
         'autoincrement' => true,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('users_id', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
    $this->hasColumn('pais_id', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'fixed' => false,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'primary' => false,
         'notnull' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
         ));
}

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->hasOne('Model_Users as Users', array(
         'local' => 'users_id',
         'foreign' => 'id'));

    $this->hasOne('Model_Pais as Pais', array(
         'local' => 'pais_id',
         'foreign' => 'id'));
}
}
```

Now what I want to be able to retrieve,...if not clear enough is the fields called pais from the pais table that match with my current user id. How do I do this with Doctrine?

EDIT:

```
//Added to Model_Users class


public function saveUser($user) {
    $this->email = $user['email'];
    $this->password = crypt($user['password'], $this->_salt);
    $this->url = $user['url'];
    $this->responsable = $user['responsable'];
    $this->role = $user['role'];
    $this->fecha = Zend_Date::now()->toString('yyyyMMddHHmmss');
    $id = $this->save();
}


//Users table schema
Users:
  connection: 0
  tableName: users
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    email:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(250)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    url:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    responsable:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    role:
      type: string(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    fecha:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    PlanillaUsers:
      local: id
      foreign: users_id
      type: many
    UsersHasPais:
      local: id
      foreign: users_id
      type: many
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller write a query something like

```
  $cu = current_user_id // you'll have to set this your self from a session variable etc
  $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->select('p.pais')   
       ->from('Model_Pais p')
       ->leftJoin('p.Model_UsersHasPais s')
       ->leftJoin('s.Model_Users u')
        ->where('u.id = ?',$cu); 
    $result = $q->fetchArray();
```

Comment: @Graham I'm getting an `Unknown relation alias Model_UsersHasPais` exception

Comment: @la_f0ka I'm new to the framework myself, check that your Apache error log for this I've seen it but can't remember what causes it. I think it may be a missing ' or , from a line in your model setup code but I'm not 100%.

Comment: @la_f0ka Or try changing the query to the following leftJoin->('p.Model_UsersHasPais s') ->leftJoin(p.Model_Users u') ie drop the s before Model_Users and replace with p

Comment: thanks a lot for your help @Graham that was it...I've called it from the view so I could get the id's since I'm looping this for all my users... which might not be the best way to go about this...

Comment: @la_f0ka As I understand from what I'm reading you should have the query as part of an action and then add it to the view but then again I'm new to the Framework and just going by the book I'm reading Zend Framework A Beginners Guide, It may be worth looking at as it used Doctrine as its ORM

Comment: sure @Graham, I'll have a look at it. And while we're at it, have you had this kind of exception while trying to save a form to the db? `Message: Validation failed in class Model_Users 1 field had validation error: * 1 validator failed on fecha (type)` The column to which it's referring to is  `$this->hasColumn('fecha', 'timestamp', null, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));`

Comment: it's just a timestamp and I added it like this: `Zend_Date::now()->toString('yyyyMMddHHmmss') `... which is the correct format for it... so I don't know what's the deal with it. This framework is starting to piss me off, but I'll have a look at this book and see if I find the answer there before getting rid of it.

Comment: @la_f0ka Sorry connection went last night. No I haven't had this issue sorry I created my forms by matching each element to the field in the table that I was creating/updating records for. Have you created a element on your form that holds the timestamp?

Comment: @Graham ... I don't really add the date from the form but from a method I added to the Model_Users. I updated the post so you can check it. I don't need that date for anything else but keeping track of when was the user created and when was the last time he logged in.

Comment: @la_f0ka Ok I'm not using zend date, why not try crating a php variable to hold the timestamp as part of your function and save that to the database.

Comment: @Graham I ended up setting the field to get the current time and date on update and allowing the model to be null. That helped remove the validation problem.